# how to open an https site in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i tried using startTLS method.but didn't obtain the result.

Comment: can you post the rest of you code here?

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection automatically handles https.  Just give it an https URL.